# Como faço para Agrupar textos em MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot

Tentei procurar uma solução para este caso, e preciso da ajuda de vocês.

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
hora    data        tarefa
10:00   02/01/19    A
10:00   03/01/19    B
11:00   02/01/19    C
```

Considerando que hoje é 02/01/2019, ao fazer o pivot table abaixo:

```
SELECT      hora
        ,   CASE WHEN data = CURDATE() 
            THEN tarefa 
            ELSE NULL 
            END AS campo_1
        ,   CASE WHEN data = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
            THEN tarefa
            ELSE NULL
            END AS campo_2
FROM        tabela
WHERE       data BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
GROUP BY    hora
        ,   data 
ORDER BY    hora
```

Eu obtenho a seguinte saída:

```
hora    Campo_1     Campo_2
10:00   A           
10:00               B
11:00   C
```

Porém, eu gostaria de obter:

```
hora    Campo_1     Campo_2
10:00   A           B
11:00   C
```

- EM SUMA, não consigo AGRUPAR a hora para que apareça apenas uma linha com 10:00, e as tarefas A e B nesta mesma linha, abaixo de suas respectivas datas.

Agradeço desde já por alguma solução.

Comment: Você verificou se a função GROUP_CONCAT(expr) não atende a suas necessidades?

Comment: utilizei o GRUP_CONCAT, mas ele retorna a seguinte saída:

10:00, 10:00 A,  ,B

Não era bem o que eu esperava. Obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que um sub-select dê conta do recado:

```
select 
     hora as horaH, 
     tarefa, 
     (select tarefa from tabela where data= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)  and hora = horaH) 
from tabela where data = CURDATE()
```

Isso atende ao caso em questão, não sei se podem ter mais de uma tarefa na mesma hora e dia, mas aí é questão de você adaptar o código.

Comment: Carla, para este exemplo de tabela funciona, mas se adicionar mais uma tarefa no mesmo dia da tarefa B, gera o erro: a subconsulta retorna mais de um registro. Obrigado pela sugestão.

Answer (score 0):

Meu grande amigo Alan respondeu essa questão, como ele não tem conta, respondi à pergunta:

```
SELECT  hora,
    MAX(CASE WHEN data = curdate() THEN tarefa ELSE NULL END) as campo_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN data = DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN tarefa ELSE NULL END) as campo_2
FROM tabela 
where data between curdate() and DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
GROUP BY hora
ORDER BY hora
```

Obrigado a todos.